# How can Boost.Asio create a buffer object of size equal to the size of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

Consider the following the lines (Boost/C++):

```
char d1[128];
size_t bytes_transferred = sock.receive(boost::asio::buffer(d1));
```

The Boost.Asio documentation states that a buffer of size 128 is created.

But how can Boost determine the size of the array? I've already read several questions, where the answer is that the size of an array cannot be determined in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is template specialization for arrays with size known at compile time http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload7.html

```
template<
    typename PodType,
    std::size_t N>
mutable_buffers_1 buffer(
    PodType (&data)[N]);
```

In C++ 'char[5]', 'char[128]' and 'char*' are different types so compiler can take advantage of this http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/#cpp

Comment: For a "newbie" to Boost could you elaborate on your answer giving a little more detail?

The array created in the example is a "pure" C++ array, it is not a Boost array?

Comment: Thanks! Is the size of the array like char[5] stored somewhere in memory? Why is N declared as a template parameter? The template is "template <typename T, size_t N>" - does the compiler at compile-time bind the N-variable to the size of the array, or is it done at run-time ?

Comment: It is at compile-time available as long as You pass that additional information. After casting 'char[N]' to 'char*' it is no longer available.

Comment: So just be to clear, the size of the array is associated with the array type e.g. the type char[N] is associated with N (N can be deduced from char[N]). This is used to infer N at compile-time. But if the size is associated with the type, why can't the size be deduced at run-time?

Comment: If You want to have some generic function that prints size it must take generic parameter like 'char*' so every 'char[N]' can be casted to it, but 'char*' no longer have information about size, it is just pointer to one char or string. If You do not want such function then  You have to print size where it is known size at compile-time and run-time no needed.

Comment: Thanks! The function you describe doesn't exist right - you cannot have such generic function?